# How to get colorbox request URL within colorbox content

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

I'm opening a colorbox within jsp as follows:

```
$.colorbox({maxHeight:"100%", href:'<c:url value="/html/dashboard_report.html" />?organization=${organizationKey}&category=${chartCategory}&severity=' + selection[0].row});
```

within my dashboard_report.html (which IS html, not JSP) using javascript I want to get the request so I can use the querystring to make further ajax calls to populate some data.  `window.location.href` doesn't work because the window location hasn't changed.

Do I just store the applicable parameters in global vars when the colorbox is opened and read those in the colorbox content or is there some other way?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use JSP to execute JS. Do you mean you're writing the JSP, and it's creating the script for you, then trying to execute?

In above case you can do something like:

```
$.colorbox.settings.maxHeight = "100%";
$.colorbox.settings.href = "http://someURL.com";
```

at the begning of your script and leverage them later dynamically, and those are only a couple of the available properties you can set to defaults... I'm not sure what you're trying to do can't accomplished without an nested AJAX call even though I'm opposed to doing that when possible.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I mentioned that it was JSP just so nobody would be confused by the syntax in the href.  Obviously it renders to html and the javascript then opens the colorbox at the appropriate time.  The question is whether the html content that is within the colorbox (and yes, it is pure html) can "see" the request that generated it, specifically the request parameters.  As I said in the question, window.location.href contains the url for the current page, not the content loaded via ajax in the colorbox, so I was wondering about other options.

Comment: have it generated somewhere in the generated stuff that gets loaded into the colorbox, if the colorbox takes an href (or location instead of just an html string, or even an html string) you place in the body a data-action="blah='',foo='',bar=''". Then use jQuery to extract it into an associative array. Bingo you have your url, but I think it may also be in the iFrame surrounding the element as well. Use firebug to snoop around a colorbox when it's open, and this should be helpful: `var container = $('.cboxIframe').contents().find(".whatEver");`